# pulling future actions using take in redux-saga won't make API calls

Tags: redux-saga

I have a situation where I fetch a report from APIs and then bring data for each of the charts in the report. If I implement a watcher like this:

```
function* watchGetChartDataInReport() {
    yield takeEvery(types.CHART_DATA_FOR_REPORT_REQUEST, fetchChartData);
}
```

and my fetchChartData looks like this:

```
export function* fetchChartData(params) {
    try {
        console.log(params);
        const result = yield call(Api.getChartDataForReport, params.params.chartid, params.params.date, params.params.dimensionFilters, params.params.compare);
        console.log(result);
        yield [
            put({ type: types.CHART_DATA_FOR_REPORT_SUCCESS, data: result.response.data, chartId: result.response.cid }),
              ];
         } catch (error) {
         yield put({ type: types.CHART_DATA_FOR_REPORT_FAILURE, error });
     }
}
```

it works fine. But I wanted more control so that I can cancel this task if the user switches to another report before data for all charts are fetched. Also, if a filter etc is applied to the report, I wanted to cancel the task for fetching data. So I am trying with another approach where I have more control on the execution. My new watcher looks like this:

```
function* watchGetChartDataInReport() {
    while (true) {
        const action = yield take(types.CHART_DATA_FOR_REPORT_REQUEST);
        yield fork(fetchChartData, action.params);
    }
}
```

and I expect that at this stage, both should work the same. Except that in second case, It is calling the `fetchChartData` but the call to API is not happening. It logs the params sent to the function and that's it. In my case, I made this sample call for two charts and twice I got the params logged to console.

Is there anything wrong with the way I am implementing this takeEvery on my own? Any leads would be helpful

Comment: Hm, the default behaviour of takeEvery is `yield fork(fetchChartData, action);` not `yield fork(fetchChartData, action.params);` .. but I guess that is intentional?

Comment: I would doublecheck (with anotehr console.log, that Api.getChartDataForReport is really not called. If so, try replacing the ` const result = yield call(Api....` with just `Api.getChartDataForReport(...).then(function() {})` and see if that works.

Comment: There was an exception happening that prevented the api call. This issue is resolved.